# Converting BInary Block to Float

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am using Python to convert a block of binary data into its equivalent Float data. The code which I have written works well in Python Version 2.7, But the same fails in Python 3.4

```
import sys
import struct

start = 1500
stop = 1600
step = 10

with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Output.bin", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(2)
    readNext = int(byte[1])
    byte = f.read(int(readNext))
    byte = f.read(4)

    while (len(byte) > 3):
        measurement = struct.unpack('<f4', byte)
        start = start + 10
        print(start, measurement)
        byte = f.read(4)
```

The binary Block data looks as below

"#220&û<êŒûvÃ§æýTûz£¯÷ßwÎ"

The first bytes is always #, followed by a number which says the number of following bytes which are Number, in this case it is 2, so it's followed by 20. After this comes the real data. Each Reading in 4 bytes long and to be converted into float using little endian format.

Output when Run in Python 2.7:

```
(1510, (-5.711601726275634e+25,))
(1520, (-246.98333740234375,))
(1530, (8723971440640.0,))
(1540, (-2.9736910156508145e-10,))
(1550, (-1039662528.0,))
```

Code I am running in Python 3.4:

```
import sys
import struct

start = 1500
stop = 1600
step = 10

with open("/home/pi/Desktop/Output.bin", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(2)
    byte = byte.decode('UTF-8') #I had to convert to read the Byte
    readNext = byte[1] # Reading the First Digit
    byte = f.read(int(readNext)) # Skip the Integer values
    byte = f.read(4) # The Actual Data

    while (len(byte) > 3):
        measurement = struct.unpack('<f4', byte)
        start = start + 10
        print(start, measurement)
        byte = f.read(4)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/MultiProbe/bin2float.py", line 17, in <module>
    measurement = struct.unpack('<f4', byte)
struct.error: repeat count given without format specifier
```

How can I modify it to get the Output similar to what I get when running in Python2.7

Answer (score 2):

you provided a repeat count but you actually need 1 decoded float (you're trying to decode 4 floats here)

It worked in python 2, probably because of a bug in the older versions of python ([struct allows repeat spec. without a format specifier](http://bugs.python.org/issue3129))

```
measurement = struct.unpack('<f', byte)
```

should do the trick.